# Is it an undefined behavior to access a pointer to an empty vector element?

Tags: c++

This code works as expected:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> tab;
if(!&tab[0])std::cout<<"null";
```

But I am not sure if it's legal to treat `&tab[0]` as null when the vector is empty.

What I am expecting is `&tab[0]` to be null, not if the vector is empty or not.

It's just so that I can pass it to a function that accepts `const unsigned char*`

Comment: Of course that's UB.

Comment: The element is not uninitialized. It does not exist.

Comment: @LogicStuff : `uninitialize vector` element

Comment: what do you mean with "works as expected?"

Comment: @tobi303 : I am checking if it's null, and I am expecting null, and it does at least on my compiler..

Comment: then your expectations are wrong :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you meant *unitialized (vector element)* or *(uninitialized vector) element*, but your example is neither. It's an initialized vector of zero elements.

`a.operator[n]` is defined to have semantics of `*(a.begin()+n)`, and with begin = end for an empty vector, you're dereferencing an end iterator. The behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written the code definitely involves Undefined Behavior, and is bad practice because it accesses uninitialized memory.

This, however, would be perfectly fine and legal:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> tab(1);
if(!&tab[0])std::cout<<"null";
```

Even though `tab[0]` has not had a value assigned to it, the pointer has a valid section of memory to point to. I can't recall if there are any guarantees about the *value* of `tab[0]`, but that's not important to the code you've written.

Comment: It doesn't print null

Comment: Writing code with undefined behaviour is worse that just "bad practice".

Comment: *"This, however, would be perfectly fine and legal:"* True, but not very useful. The stuff in the `if` is dead code.

Comment: @Jahid It's not going to print null if the pointer is pointing to data (which it is). If you're expecting the code to check whether the vector has any data or not, you should be writing something like `if(tab.size() == 0) std::cout << "null";` or similar code. Don't try to do weird pointer tricks to get that information.

Comment: @LogicStuff *"default-constructed"*  Value initialized actually.

Comment: @Xirema `std::vector` even has an `empty` member function to make that check even more concise.

Comment: I need a null pointer not if it's empty, besides tab.empty would be easier to write..

Comment: @Klaus In my code, `tab` is initialized like so: `std::vector<unsigned char> tab(1);`. That will guarantee that there is A) a valid pointer, and B) that that pointer points to allocated space for at least one `char`. `tab.begin()` is not going to equal `tab.end()` in my code.